# XMLHttpRequest is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, phpword

I have a button who downloads a docx file on clientside. The file is generated with PHPWord. In Chrome it is working but not in firefox:

js:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "/vendor/gendocx.php", true);
req.responseType = "blob";

req.onload = function (event) {
    var blob = req.response;
    console.log(blob.size);
    console.log(blob);
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download="TEST_this out.docx";
    link.click();
};

req.send(content);
```

php:

```
$filename = 'TEST_this out';

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpword, 'Word2007');

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');

$objWriter->save($filename);
$objWriter->save("php://output");

exit;
```

I already tried other solutions on this site, but without success. Hope you can help me with this issue.

there is no error message. This is the result of `blob`

[image]

Comment: "is not working" is not a good problem statement. What error messages are displayed in the console? When you add `console.log` statements, what lines of code run successfully?

Comment: I would find it surprising (but not impossible) that Chrome and Firefox handle the Ajax fetch differently here. I would not be surprised to learn that they handle `.download` and/or automated  `.click()` differently. Where does the failure occur? Does `onload` run, or not?

Comment: @quentin in chrome, all code is running successfully. It appears the usual button on the bottom of the browser to open the file. But in firefox, it does unfortunately nothing. No error on console, status code is 200.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Appearently on firefox I have to add `document.body.appendChild(a)` to the dom.

```
req.onload = function (event) {
    var blob = req.response;
    console.log(blob.size);
    console.log(blob);
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(link.href);
    link.download="TEST_this_out.docx";
    link.click();
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }, 500)
};
```

thanks anyway for your help!